# Implied volatility from American options using python

Tags: implied-volatility, american-options, python, lattice

I am currently trying to construct volatility surface from american option prices (using Cox-Ross-Rubinstein tree) in Python 2.7. Below you can find the code I came up with. Any corrections would be welcome, however my biggest issue is performance. Single implied vol takes around 0.03 seconds to calculate. I guess that is because of the loops I use for moving backwards on the tree. Does anybody have an idea how to redesign the code to avoid looping for every step on the tree?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import newton

# test parameters

n_steps=200    #number of steps
time=2.0    #time to maturity
strike=100.0    # strike price
price=102.0     # current stock price
time_step=float(time/n_steps) #length of a time step

R=0.05    #interest rate
D=0.02    #dividend yield
df_base=[1.0]    #discount factor for Today e.g. DF(TOday,Today)
df_base.extend([np.exp(-R*time_step)]*n_steps)
DFs=np.cumprod(df_base)    #vector of discount factors for all the steps


forwards=price*np.cumprod([np.exp((R-D)*time_step)]*n_steps)    # final version will make it possible to enter a vector of forward prices

call_price=17.3285914343
put_price=10.5343901817  

# end of test parameters

def AmerImpliedVol(opt_price, price, forwards, strike, time,DFs,callPutInd=1.,n_steps=200,scale=1.):
    time_step=float(time/n_steps)
    time_sqrt=np.sqrt(time_step)

    horizontal=np.array(xrange(0,n_steps+1),dtype='float64')
    horizontal.shape=(1,n_steps+1)

    vertical=np.array(xrange(0,-2*n_steps-2,-2),dtype='float64')
    vertical.shape=(n_steps+1,1)

    forwards_previous=[price]
    forwards_previous.extend(forwards[:-1])
    exp_drift=np.array(forwards)/np.array(forwards_previous)

    step_DFs=np.array(DFs[1:])/np.array(DFs[:-1])

    tree_template=vertical+horizontal

    #vol=0.25
    def step_price(vol):
        power_vol=np.exp(vol*time_sqrt)
        down=1/power_vol
        p_up=(exp_drift-down)/(power_vol-down)
        p_down=1.-p_up

        tree=np.power(power_vol,tree_template)*price

        cp=callPutInd
        def payoff(values):
            return np.maximum(cp*(values-strike),0.)

        payoffs=payoff(tree[:,n_steps])
        current=payoffs

        for i in xrange(n_steps,0,-1):
            after_step=step_DFs[i-1]*(p_up[i-1]*current[:n_steps]+p_down[i-1]*current[1:])
            payoffs=payoff(tree[:,i-1])
            current[:-1]=np.maximum(after_step,payoffs[:-1])
            #current[:-1]=after_step

        return scale*current[0]-opt_price

    #return brentq(step_price,0.01,10.0,rtol=1.0e-8, maxiter=50)
    return newton(step_price,0.3)

print AmerImpliedVol(put_price,price,forwards,strike,time,DFs,-1.)
print AmerImpliedVol(call_price,price,forwards,strike,time,DFs,1.)
```

For European options simple implied volatility procedure (almost no optimization) takes around 0.0014 s per option. I understand that implying vols from american option prices is slower but a factor of 20 seems large.

I fine-tuned code a little bit:
- I removed computationally intensive power function and replaced it with numpy cumprod
- I took payoff calculations outside of the loop
- I decreased accuracy to 0.5e-04, as higher accuracy could be considered noise

Now it takes around 0.015s per option.

```
def AmerImpliedVol2(opt_price, price, forwards, strike, time,DFs,callPutInd=1.,n_steps=200,scale=1.):
    time_step=float(time/n_steps)
    time_sqrt=np.sqrt(time_step)

    forwards_previous=[price]
    forwards_previous.extend(forwards[:-1])
    exp_drift=np.array(forwards)/np.array(forwards_previous)

    step_DFs=np.array(DFs[1:])/np.array(DFs[:-1])

    tree_template=vertical+horizontal

    #vol=0.25
    def step_price(vol):
        power_vol=np.exp(vol*time_sqrt)
        down=1/power_vol
        p_up=(exp_drift-down)/(power_vol-down)
        p_down=1.-p_up

        horizontal=np.ones(shape=(1,n_steps+1))*power_vol
        horizontal[0,0]=1.
        horizontal=np.cumprod(horizontal,axis=1)

        vertical=np.ones(shape=(n_steps+1,1))/(power_vol*power_vol)
        vertical[0,0]=1.
        vertical=np.cumprod(vertical,axis=0)

        tree=price*(vertical*horizontal)

        cp=callPutInd
        def payoff(values):
            return np.maximum(cp*(values-strike),0.)

        payoffs=payoff(tree)
        del tree
        current=payoffs[:,n_steps]

        for i in xrange(n_steps,0,-1):
            after_step=step_DFs[i-1]*(p_up[i-1]*current[:i]+p_down[i-1]*current[1:])
            current=np.maximum(after_step,payoffs[:i,i-1])
            #print current
            #current[:-1]=after_step

        return scale*current[0]-opt_price

    seed=0.3

    return newton(step_price,seed,tol=0.5e-04)
```

Comment: Have you found a way to further optimize your code?